# Boot Repair Ubuntu 14.04-(HP g7 pavilion 2247us)

Tags: dual-boot

I have a HP g7 pavilion that came with windows 8. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 using Pendledrive (I think the spelling is correct).EDIT: I will be using YUMI exclusively from this point on to establish some consistency. I turned on Legacy option in BIOS which disabled secure boot by default to boot to the USB. While I "tried" Ubuntu I used the default install settings that were located in the "install" desktop icon that was, of course, located on Ubuntu’s desktop.

After  restart I received a message stating "there is an error, windows cant start, a file is missing"... Following on screen prompts I choose Ubuntu as the default system (of course) and tried again to load with no luck. Same message of file missing, windows cant start. This time though Ubuntu was the  chosen default system and I didn’t want windows.

Returning to bios set-up,  disabled Legacy support and loaded from factory defaults. I then downloaded boot-repair live, used YUMI to create a live USB and went back in bios, changed settings and booted to USB. Given several options (I dont remember all as Ive only seen the screen once) to execute tasks, I choose to "fix file systems" or similar. I am now at a screen that states in side a prompt box:
  Continuing will remount your / file system in read/write mode and mount any other file system defined in /ect/fstab.

```
        Yes.                    No
```

The very bottom of the screen there are two lines of txt that read:

Fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sda12: clean, 207649/20676608 files, 2350946/82684928 blocks
I can not do anything at this point. The only action I receive is the flash of the cursor.  The keyboard arrows return 
^[[C^[ [D
and the like with letters A through D inside the brackets. 
What to do now?
I suppose I can leave the HP in the current state as no smoke is evolving from it yet, but the urge to introduce my car tire and this HP (Heaping Pile) is becoming uncontrollable.  I need windows for school so hence the dual boot instead of a Virtual environment.  Please, some guidance. Im not a programmer but I can read and follow directions in which I am seeking now.

I am editing now on the Ubuntu 14.04 desktop! Although I am using Ubuntu now, I am unable to access the console with my password and am only allowed access by use of the default guest account. When attempting to sign in, after entering my password I am shown a blank, black screen for proximately 10, maybe 15 seconds and then returned to the sign/login page. If I press enter, with no password typed or if I enter an incorrect password there is displayed directly above the txt box the message indicating an incorrect password.